# Unable to set timeout variables in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hikaricp

I want to set common timeout variables in JDBC/Hikari pool.
To do this, I tried variables in JDBC URL and in Hikari config, but none seems to work.

```java
HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://*/*?wait_timeout=77&interactive_timeout=78");
hikariConfig.setUsername("*");
hikariConfig.setPassword("*");
hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(65 * 1000);
hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(66 * 1000);

HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
Connection connection1 = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
Statement statement1 = connection1.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet1 = null;

resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery("show variables like '%timeout%'");
```

**Still getting default values here**

```java
while (resultSet1.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet1.getString(1) + " " + resultSet1.getString(2));
}
```

Comment: The `setConnectionTimeout` and `setIdleTimeout` are configuration of the HikariCP connection pool and do not affect (or effect) the MySQL side of things.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel agreed. I want to know way for setting mysql connection properties like wait_timeout/interactive_timeout that hikaricp would be maintaining.

Comment: I don't normally use MySQL, check the documentation of MySQL Connector/J if it has [connection property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for it. At first glance, the only likely candidate is `connectionAttributes`, but that is only a guess on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, we can set datasource properties via

```
hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty()
```

ref: https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp